Joy from smartphone via wifi
I'm a ros beginner student, sorry,
I would like to create a program to send its coordinates data to joy_node using a virtual controller that is moved by touch on a smartphone with ros2 humble. is there a good documentation or an application or program that already exists?
I want to be able to do this via wifi and not via bluetooth.
I know it's a difficult task for me, but I really need it, thank you in advance.
